# Parse where clause query from Rest Get call

Tags: java, sql, rest

I am receiving a where clause from Rest API Get and I should convert properties, So I need to convert this string to java object with logical and .... for example :

```
String where = "prop = 1 and prop2 = 'ssdf' or date > 20121204";
```

Is there any java library that converts where clause to java object with separate condition and operator ?

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html

Comment: My question si how to parse a query that you are receiveing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this library :
https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser

Seems like very good for query parsing

Answer (score 0):

Using JSqlParser one could use an already implemented utility method to parse conditions like in your where clause:

```
String where = "prop = 1 and prop2 = 'ssdf' or date > 20121204";
Expression expr = CCJSqlParserUtil.parseCondExpression(where);
System.out.println(expr);
```

This works with **JSqlParser V0.9.x** (https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser)

Then you have an object tree with separated operators, ands, ors, values. This one you could traverse using the ExpressionVisitorAdapter, e.g.

```
ExpressionVisitorAdapter visitor = new ExpressionVisitorAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void visit(Column column) {
        System.out.println(column);
    }
};

expr.accept(visitor);
```